# grepcode kind of browsing in svn

Tags: java, svn

Is there any GrepCode kind of code browser for svn.
By GrepCode kind i mean the one with hyperlinks, you can click on Java class name sand navigate to the java class.

Thanks,
Keshava.

Comment: FishEye from Atlassian does it nicely

Comment: I have used fisheye, but it does add hyperlinks, it just shows code like in a code block. Are you using any plugins with fisheye ?

Comment: Nope. I was thinking about the breadcrumbs thing. `Opengrok` does this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[Opengrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) enables you to click through source Java classes and cross reference them.

FishEye is generally more user friendly but lacks this specific feature. They have a [JIRA](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/FE-2529) open against this.